# Merge PDFs, fix page numbering and compress

Tags: pdftex, pdf, page-numbering, pdfpages

Say there is a book that has been split into several PDFs. I want to do two things:

1. Merge the PDFs and reduce the size of the resulting PDF.
2. Fix the page numbering.

(1) can be done with `pdftk` or Ghostscript. For me, Ghostscript creates considerably smaller PDFs and is the only program (of the two) available on my PC.

Example:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -q -sOutputFile=output.pdf input_1.pdf input_2.pdf [...] input_n.pdf
```

Why is (2) a problem at all? Because different books start counting page numbers on different pages whereas your PDF reader starts counting at page 1 if you don't do anything. This can be fixed with an empty document, the package `pdfpages`, `\setcounter`, and `\pagenumbering`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{4}
\includepdf[pages=-]{input_1_with_TOC.pdf}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\includepdf[pages=-]{input_2.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{input_3.pdf}
% ...
\end{document}
```

My problem is now: I want to fix the page numbering *and* create a small PDF but calling pdflatex and then Ghostscript creates a PDF that is considerably bigger than a PDF that has been merged with Ghostscript.

How do I create PDFs as small as with (1) while having (2)?

EDIT: Forgot to add `hyperref` to the LaTeX code.

Comment: Is TeX really the best tool for this job?  There are PDF libraries for many scripted languages that could renumber pages

Comment: If you are dealing with the pdf outputs only, there is no feasible way to modify the page numbers of the pagination. From the pdf's point of view they are just digit (or character!) sequences that happen to be positioned at some peculiar place of the page.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: There are the page numbers in the text ("on the paper") and there are the page numbers that are shown by your PDF reader. I want to change the latter.

Comment: GhostScript likely reduces the size of the PDFs because it reduces the resolution of included bitmap images. Do you really want that?

Comment: @Martin Schröder: Yes, I want to reduce the resolution. Otherwise I would have used Ghostscript with -dPDFSETTINGS=/preprint or only pdfpages.

Answer (score 2):

1. Merge with Ghostscript.
2. Use `pdfpages` on the Ghostscript output like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{4}
\includepdf[pages={1-17}]{gs-output.pdf} % contains table of contents
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\includepdf[pages={18-}]{gs-output.pdf} % Rest of the book
\end{document}
```